# xcode 6.1 does not add document types

Tags: ios, iphone, info.plist, xcode6.1

I need to register my ios app as a routing app, I'm trying to add a document types entry in my info.plist file with xcode 6.1, but fail. When I try to fill in the document types form the system works slowly and then doesn't store the entry.
Is this a kind of bug or what? Where I wrong?

Comment: I've OS X Yosemite, with OS X Mavericks I didn't have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I finally solve it by adding the property from another machine with Maverick OS. My machine already done the upgrade to Yosemite and wasn't unable to add the values in this property.
I think this will be soon a know problem.

Comment: Thanks! I hope there will be soon a better solution.